# Centering UL Images in DIV tag

Tags: css

I struck up with CSS issue. I have a situation as below

```
<div>
<ul>
<li> <img src="a.jpg" ></li>
<li> <img src="a.jpg" ></li>
<li> <img src="a.jpg" ></li>
<li> <img src="a.jpg" ></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to center all my UL tag, but images has to be left align.

I am getting images as center, when I use text-align: center. But, last image in ul is displaying in center which I don't want to display.

Can any one helps me?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Write like this:

```
div{text-align:center}
ul{
 display:inline-block;
 *display:inline;/* for IE7 */
 *zoom:1;
 text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: I think the second selector should be `ul li`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><span></span><a href="">Add Some Text</a></li>
    <li><span></span><a href="">Add Some Text</a></li>
    <li><span></span><a href="">Add Some Text</a></li>
    <li><span></span><a href="">Add Some Text</a></li>
    <li><span></span><a href="">Add Some Text</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#menu li {
 clear: left;
}

#menu li a {
 padding: 5px 0 0 40px;
 display:block;
}

#menu li span {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 height: 32px;
 width:32px;
 background: url(images/icon.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Calling the icon image by using a span tag then having control over your text and icon image through your css is the way to go. Of course you can remove the text

Here's the example http://jsfiddle.net/DUjfd/